# It is possible to configure Restlet to use BufferedHttpEntity?

Tags: restlet, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm getting an intermittent exception `org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Unbuffered entity enclosing request can not be repeated.` when using Apache HTTP client library 4.x with Restlet 1.1. The request entity is of type `InputRepresentation`, which is associated with `ByteArrayInputStream` of known size, with size specified at the time of instantiation.

The exception is thrown in method `writeRequestBody` in class `org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod`

```
  if ((this.repeatCount > 0) && !requestEntity.isRepeatable()) {
            throw new ProtocolException(
                "Unbuffered entity enclosing request can not be repeated.");
  }
```

To be honest, the cause of this exception is not clear (especially due to its intermittent nature). However, some research suggests that using Apache BufferedHttpEntity to wrap the request entity should help.

Is there a way to inform Restlet to use BufferedHttpEntity when passing its request to the Apache library for handling? What could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entity content stream can be reproduced (repeated), which is certainly the case with ByteArrayInputStream, there is no need for BufferedHttpEntity. One just needs to make sure that the original request entity returns a new instance of InputStream from HttpEntity#getContent() method and HttpEntity#isRepeatable() returns true.

Please note though that `org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException` is from an older (EOL-ed) version 3.x. Please make sure you do not have some kind of version mix-up in your application

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, I have to work with Restlet abstractions that do not provide access to HttpEntity. However, the idea to check dependency was valuable -- it turned out Restlet 1.x provides its own dependency to Apache HTTP Client version 3.1.

Comment: @01es The point I was trying to make was that there was not reason for an entity backed by a byte array to be non-repeatable and the whole problem was likely being a bug in Restlet 1.1

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the Restlet Framework connector integrating with Apache HTTP Client.

In version 2.0 of RF, there is a new ClientResource class with "retryAttempts" and "retryDelay" property that provides the same behavior, but based on the Restlet abstractions.